# why "Only run in command line mode" show when run "php artisan serve"

Tags: laravel, laravel-websockets

when run "php artisan serve" and open browser with url localhost:8000 show Only run in command line mode

i use this library https://github.com/zhouaini528/binance-php/blob/master/README.md#Websocket

Comment: how are you running this command?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.